# How can I pass JS arrays to C# webforms?

Tags: javascript, c#, arrays, asp.net, webforms

```
<head runat="server">
   <title></title>
   <script>
       const array1 = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];
   </script>
</head>
<body>
   <form id="form1" runat="server">
       <div>
           <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click1" />
       </div>
   </form>
</body>

   public partial class JSPassWebForm : System.Web.UI.Page
   {
       protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {

       }

       protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           for (int i = 0; i < array1.Length; i++)
               Response.Write(array1[i] + "<br>");
       }
   }
```

How can I do to pass the JS array to C#? (I don't want to use ajax if possible)

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create one hidden field on the view and pass your array to that field. THen you can access that hidden field's value inside your method.

Something like this. Change your view to this:

```
 <div>
        <input id="HiddenField" type="hidden" runat="server" />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClientClick="AssignValue()"  Text="Button"
            onclick="Button1_Click1" />
    </div>

     <script>
        function AssignValue() {
        var array1 = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];
        document.getElementById("HiddenField").value = array1;
    }
</script>
```

And you can read `HiddenField` in method, something like this:

```
    protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            for (int i = 0; i < HiddenField.Value.Length; i++){
           Response.Write(HiddenField.Value[i] + "<br>");}
    }
```

This is just a Sample code to give you an idea.

Comment: What exactly will be the *string* value of that `HiddenField.Value`? Not the array you want in any case

Comment: Very good. I did it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do it. But i prefer one like this:

Set your form's `onsubmit` attribute a js method:

```
<form id="myForm" ... onsubmit="serializeArray();">
... 
<script>
    function serializeArray() {
        let hdn = document.createElement('input');
        hdn.type = 'hidden';
        hdn.name = 'array1'; //Name property is important. Because you will use this value at your c# code to get value of this array
        hdn.value = JSON.stringify(array1);
        document.getElementById('myForm').appendChild(hdn);
    } 
</script>
```

Then on your server side you can get this variable using `Request.Form`. For example (using Newtonsoft.Json):

```
var array1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourArrayType>(Request.Form["array1"]);
```

Comment: not json parse - stringify!

Comment: I tested but failed but what should I enter in the <YourArrayType> entry?

Comment: I mean if you have a model class, you can parse it as List<ModelClass>. For your example, you can use Lİst<string> to parse this value as array.